# One systemd service depend on another

Tags: systemd

I'm trying to refactor a single systemd service/program into multiple programs and services. My single big service looked like:

```
[Unit]
Description=Runs the App loop
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 -u /App/mainLoop
WorkingDirectory=/App
StandardOutput=journal
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I cobbled this together from other examples. What I want now is two services:

*ServiceA*

```
[Unit]
Description=Initializes some things
After=network-online.target # Question 1

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 -u /App/startup
WorkingDirectory=/App
StandardOutput=journal
Restart=on-failure # Question 2

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

*ServiceB*

```
[Unit]
Description=Runs the App loop
After=network-online.target # Question 3

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 -u /App/mainLoop
WorkingDirectory=/App
StandardOutput=journal
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target # Question 4
```

So I have multiple question points here (referenced by the comments above):

1. I don't need the network to be alive anymore for this. What should I put here instead? How does one browse possible targets?
2. I want the startup app to just run once at startup, never again. I assume I need to change the `Restart` flag to something else, but what?
3. Rather than after the network of course, I want this to run after service A completes AND ONLY IF it managed to exit with a 0 and write a file. How do I make it start after the one time service A starts successfully?
4. More of 3 I guess. I'm still fuzzy on what the difference is between the `WantedBy` target and the `After` target. Is the `WantedBy` basically the group it belongs to, and the `After` the one that it has to be serialized after?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. The targets depend on OS, which you haven't listed here. Probably `default.target`. You can view targets and what uses by looking at the output of `systemctl list-dependencies`
2. Just remove "Restart" entirely
3. The initial service should be `Type=oneshot`. It will be up to the service to properly exit based on whether or not it wrote the file you require. You may want to use `ExecStartPre` to launch initialization scripts instead.
4. `WantedBy` tells `systemd` to start the service when it enters the given target. `After` says to start the unit after all units in the given target (or unit) have completed.

Comment: I'm running Debian Jessie on a headless SBC. I put `default.target` as you suggested, but it doesn't run. `find / | grep default.target` actually shows 2 such files. A symlink at `/lib/systemd/system/default.target -> graphical.target` and another normal file at `/usr/lib/systemd/user/default.target` which includes things like `After=basic.target`. Not sure what to make of all of that. :(

Comment: Shouldn't #3 be `Requires: ...`, unless Service A is made a `Type=oneshot`? Otherwise, it starts it _after_ but not once Service A is considered ready... Correct?

Comment: About #1: I think the line can just be removed if network is not required anymore.